# How to assign my own auto-incrementing field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My application needs to automatically assign a number (starting at 1001) to records of a certain type (think of something like a check register).  The number should be displayed as part of the input screen, but of course not modifiable.

How do I do this in Rails?

Note:  this has nothing to do with the id field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can only set one `auto_increment` column to a table and that needs to be defined as the `primary key`too. So this isnt an option for you because the `id` field is the `primary key` of your table.

So you need to do this application internal. Just add an `integer` column to the table:

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :integer
```

Then add a method to your model that figures out the value of the column in the last dataset created.

```
def self.last_<column_name>_used
     return last.<column_name> unless last.nil?
     return 1000
end

def self.next_<column_name>_to_use
     last_<column_name>_used+1
end
```

Then you can use `filter` to automaticly assign the value of Model.next__to_use to the  which should be incremended and you can also use it to get the value that should be displayed in the form. The form can easyly be disabled using jQuery.

```
$('#model_<column_name>').attr("disabled", true);
```

Hope this is what you needed!